# How to delete gnome web from the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, gnome3, epiphany

I would to know how to delete the gnome web browser from the browser. I'm not finding it's name. I can see a lot of the gnome apps by typing `gnome-` and pressing tab, but the web browser is not located there.

Comment: Welcome! By delete you mean uninstall? Could you clarify "delete the gnome web browser from the browser."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional name of the gnome web browser is Epiphany.

You can remove it with the command
`sudo apt remove epiphany-browser`

Comment: At least in gnome 3.30 the web browser is chromium, and it's called `gnome-www-browser`.